# I am making a calculator the issue is on line 42 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

cant figure out line 42 keep getting error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int' could some one advise me on how to fix it as i have been stuck on it for hrs how the code work is you run it and then you pick what type of calculation you want to do in this case area of a circle is broken and for some reason it wont work how its supposed to work is that def check checks if the string are numbers or letters and if they are numbers it will continue and if it is letters it will restart and say that you need to choose numbers not letters

```
import time
import math

def check(num1, num2):
    number1 = str(num1).isnumeric()
    if number1 == False:
        print('Bruh math not l\'anglais')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        restart()
    number2 = str(num2).isnumeric()
    if number2 == False:
        print('Bruh math not l\'anglais')
        time.sleep(2.5)
        while True:
            restart()
       
def percentage_decrease():
    original_amount = str(input("Please give me the original amount: "))
    percentage_decrease = str(input("Give me percentage to decrease: "))
    check(original_amount, percentage_decrease)
    multiplier = 1 - int(percentage_decrease) / 100
    answer = int(original_amount) * multiplier
    print("The answer is",answer)                        
def percentage_increase():
    original_amount = str(input("Please give me the original amount: "))
    percentage_increase = str(input("Give me percentage to increase: "))
    check(original_amount, percentage_increase)
    multiplier = 1 + int(percentage_increase) / 100
    answer = int(original_amount) * multiplier
    print("The an is",answer)
def power_of_x():
    num = str(input("What number would you like to find out the power off: "))
    power = str(input("what power do you to do: "))
    check(num, power)
    answer = int(num**power)
    print("The answer is",answer)
def area_circle():
    user_choice = input("Would you like to use diameter or radius?")
    if user_choice.lower() == "radius" or user_choice.lower() == "r":
        num_area_circle_radius = str(input("Please give me the radius: "))
        check(num_area_circle_radius, '0')
        anwser_area_circle = math.pi * int(num_area_circle_radius**2)
        rounded_anwser_area_circle = round(anwser_area_circle, 2)
        print("The anwser is",rounded_anwser_area_circle,"rounded 2d.p")
    elif user_choice.lower() == "diameter" or user_choice.lower() == "d":
        num_area_circle_diameter = str(input("Please give me the diameter: "))
        check(num_area_circle_diameter, '0')
        convert_diameter_radius = num_area_circle_diameter / 2
        anwser_area_circle = math.pi * int(convert_diameter_radius**2)
        rounded_anwser_area_circle = round(anwser_area_circle, 2)
        print("The anwser is",rounded_anwser_area_circle,"rounded 2d.p")                
def addition():
    num1_addition = input("First Number pls: ")
    num2_addition = input("Second Number pls: ")
    check(num1_addition, num2_addition)
    answer_addition = int(num1_addition) + int(num2_addition)
    print("The answer is",answer_addition)
def multiply():
    num1_multiply = str(input("First Number pls: "))
    num2_multiply = str(input("Second Number pls: "))
    check(num1_multiply, num2_multiply)
    answer_multiply = int(num1_multiply) * int(num2_multiply)
    print("The answer is",answer_multiply)  
def subtraction():
    num1_subtraction = str(input("First Number pls: "))
    num2_subtraction = str(input("Second Number pls: "))
    check(num1_subtraction, num2_subtraction)
    answer_subtraction = int(num1_subtraction) - int(num2_subtraction)
    print("The answer is",answer_subtraction)
def division():
    num1_division = str(input("First Number pls: "))
    num2_division = str(input("Second Number pls: "))
    check(num1_division, num2_division)
    answer_division = int(num1_division) / int(num2_division)
    print("The answer is",answer_division)
def start():
    print("These are multiple things you can do \n1)Addition \n2)Subtraction \n3)Multiplication \n4)Division \n5)Area Of Circle \n6)Power Off x \n7)Percentage Increase \n8)Percentage Decrease")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    user_operator = input("What calculation would you like to: ")
    if user_operator.lower() == "Addition" or user_operator == "1":
        addition()
    elif user_operator.lower() == "Subtraction" or user_operator == "2":
        subtraction()
    elif user_operator.lower() == "Division" or user_operator == "4":
        division()
    elif user_operator.lower() == "Multiplication" or user_operator == "3":
        multiply()
    elif user_operator.lower() == "Area of a circle" or user_operator == "5":
        area_circle()
    elif user_operator.lower() == "power of x" or user_operator == "6":
        power_of_x()
    elif user_operator.lower() == "percentage increase" or user_operator == "7":
        percentage_increase()
    elif user_operator.lower() == "percentage decrease" or user_operator == "8":
        percentage_decrease()
    else:
        start()
start()
def restart():
    user_restart = input("Do you want to do another calculation(y or n): ")
    if user_restart == "Y".lower():
        start()
    elif user_restart == "N".lower():
        print("Thank you for using my calculator.")
    else:
        start()        
    while user_restart == "Yes".lower():
        restart()
        if user_restart == "No".lower():
            user_restart = "No"
while True:
    restart()
```

Comment: You have to convert `num` and `power` to numbers *before* you do math on them, not *after*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    num = str(input("What number would you like to find out the power off: "))
    power = str(input("what power do you to do: "))
    check(num, power)
    answer = int(num**power)
```

You meant to convert "num" to int, and then take the power, you misaligned your brackets.